# How to recreate if else statements in Scala using objects?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement my own if-else like control structures in Scala using thunk code. The point is to create a control structure with the same behavior as if-else statements but a custom name. The thing is that i cannot figure out how to implement the complete case of an if else statement, i get stuck implementing the if.

```
object Si {
      def apply[U](expression:Boolean)(instruction:U):U = {
        if (expression) instruction
      }

    }
```

This piece of code doesn't compile. It says that the value Any doesn't conform to expected type U. I know what the problem is, but i cannot figure out the way to implement the "else" part.
Could anyone please give me any idea of how they would implement it?

Comment: "using thunk code" There are no thunks here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually create these kinds of DSL's by returning intermediate objects until the whole expression is complete.

```
object fi { 
  def apply[R](cond: Boolean)(then: => R): IfThen[R] = new IfThen(cond, then)

  class IfThen[R](cond: Boolean, then: => R) {
    def esle[S >: R](ethen: => S) = if (cond) then else ethen 
  }
}
```

You can then use it almost exactly like a normal `if ... else ...`. Only the `else` part is always required.

```
scala> fi (1 > 2 - 3) { Some("foo") } esle { None }
res9: Option[String] = Some(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have an `else` that also returns a U
you can return an Option[U] instead and return None in the else